# Getting object key and value from objects in a text file

Tags: javascript

I'm using fetch to get visemes from amazon polly as a text file and trying to get the value of each object key time and value key but every time I try to it gives me an undefined error and when I tried using a console.log(out[i]); it just gave me the very first quote in the curly brackets. I even tried adding a JSON.parse(out) to my code but It gave me an Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 39 error. If you need to see my source code I've attached it below. I've also attached links to this question one that shows the contents of my text file and another that shows the error I got before using the JSON.parse. I hope it helps.

```js
var viseme    = 'value';
var time      = 'time';
var bracket   = '}';
var jsonIndex = -1;
var itemHTML  = '';
var number    = '4';
               
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.text())
.then((out) => {
  console.log("Checkout this JSON!", out);
  console.log(out.substring(27, 37));
  var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(out);
  for(var i of Array(12).keys()) {
    console.log(out[1]);
    var anotherResJson = out[i]['@value'];
    console.log("jsonParsed[",i,"][@value]:",anotherResJson);
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  throw error
});
```

[image: contents of text file]

[image: output before JSON.parse]

Comment: Don't post image of code!

Comment: `out[i]` will just be a single character from your `out` string. So trying to access the property `"@value"` on the string character will give `undefined`, as string's don't have an `@value` property. If you have control over the `url` endpoint and the data that it is returning, then you can fix that so it comes back in a JSON format, as currently what you have isn't a valid JSON string (hence why you can't parse it with `JSON.parse()`). I'd be surprised if amazon doesn't provide an API that serves valid JSON (you might be looking at the wrong endpoint)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming a question.  Please note that it is not advisable to post a picture of code or text-- instead, include the text in the body of the question.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your file, from what I see in the screenshot, does not appear to be valid JSON.  What I am seeing is several individual objects with double-quotes around the values and keys, but they are separated by newlines.  This is not valid JSON and will not parse-- run the below snippet with the console open:

```js
const notActuallyJson = '{ "Batgirl": "Barbara Gordon" }\n{ "Supergirl": "Kara Zor-El" }';
console.log(notActuallyJson);
const parsed = JSON.parse(notActuallyJson);
console.log(parsed);
```

If you are looking for a data structure similar to this that is valid JSON, you want an array (`[]`) in which these objects are comma-separated:

```js
const validJson = '[\n{ "Batgirl": "Barbara Gordon" },\n{ "Supergirl": "Kara Zor-El" }\n]';
console.log(validJson);
const parsed = JSON.parse(validJson);
console.log(parsed);
```

## UPDATE

### Converting the file contents to JSON

It is hard to know exactly the situation with your file contents because you haven't shared them as text-- you've only shared them as an image.  However, if my hunch is correct and they are just valid JSON objects separated with newlines, you could wrap them with brackets and separate them with commas like so:

```js
const notActuallyJson = '{ "Batgirl": "Barbara Gordon" }\n{ "Supergirl": "Kara Zor-El" }';
const convertedToActualJson = `[${notActuallyJson.split('\n').join(',')}]`;
console.log(convertedToActualJson);
const parsed = JSON.parse(convertedToActualJson);
console.log(parsed);
```

If your file contents does *not* fit that description, then you'll need a more customized solution, which you should probably post in a separate question as it is diverging quite a bit from the original post.

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can convert it to JSON

Comment: @ChrisYoung - see edits